# how to allow cross domain requests on tomcat?

Tags: ajax, rest, cross-domain, tomcat6, same-origin-policy

I am deploying a web app on 2 separate domains, 
the first web app is a restful service deployed on tomcat 6, 
the second is a static content (html, java script), 
the java script from the static content domain will call the restful service.
but the same origin policy is not allowing this, 
my question is: how to allow cross domain requests on tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're able to focus on modern browsers, I suggest looking into a Java implementation of [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control), or `CORS`, perhaps [like this one](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html).

Mozilla introduced CORS in FF3.5 and it's since become pretty widely adopted. IE introduced a competing, stricter standard `XDomainRequest` called that doesn't leak cookie information, but only IE supports it.

[IE is slated to support CORS in IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=CORS), which makes it the technique of choice.